# Trusted Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I had to develop a Chrome Extension for a website i'm working for. I finished developing it just fine. But Chrome automatically turns it off after browser restarts, with following reason:

> This extension is not listed in the Chrome Web Store and may have been added without your knowledge.

**My question:** Is it possible to have a "Trusted" extension without publishing it to the Chrome Web Store. I don't want to publish it because it wouldn't make much sense, because it is for a very restricted number of "corporative" users.

Comment: Can you turn it into a Chrome App? It is possible to publish private chrome apps if you can. https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860?hl=en

Comment: @Ozan the main "concept" is to have a button in the top-right corner which users can click (its function very similar to "Pin" button of the Pinterest extension) and i don't know if this is possible with an app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chrome web store allows you to hide your extension from public listings. It also allows you do [inline installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation). This would allows users to install the chrome extension in their browser without ever having to leave your website. So it would be hosted in the chrome web store, trusted, but only installable from your own website.

Comment: Helpful stuff, thank you. I guess this will work in my case.